# Organizing tables and figures with captions horizontally and vertically

Tags: tables, floats

I need to organize my tables and figures (with a separate caption for each one) in the following manner:

```
--------    --------
|      |    |      |
|      |    --------
|      |      Fig 7
|      |    --------
|      |    |      |
--------    --------
 Tab 1        Tab 2
```

**EDIT:**

Seems like I miscopied one of the lines in the manual. For future reference, the way to do it using `floatrow` is in page 97 of the documentation:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf

Comment: The `floatrow` package is made for such situations.

Comment: I've tried that package, but I haven't been able to get the vertical stacking right.

Comment: Could you give a MWE of what you tried?

Comment: Seems like I miscopied one of the lines in the manual. For future reference, the way to do it using `floatrow` is in page 97 of the documentation:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf

Comment: Copy-paste error => OT.